# Power Apps change Image based on field value

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-forms, conditional, powerapps-canvas, formula

I have built a weather app in Power Apps.  I'm using the MSN weather connector to gather several basic criteria, namely "Precipitation".  So I have several images I'd like to use for sunny, cloudy, and rainy days.  I have a field that I set called "currentPrecip" which I want to change the image based on.  This line successfully gives me a gif called "mostly-cloudy" when currentPrecip equals one of these 3 phrases:

```
If(currentPrecip = "Mostly cloudy" Or "Cloudy" Or "Partly cloudy", 'mostly-cloudy', sunnygif)
```

Currently, if the currentPrecip is anything else, the image switches to a sunny gif.  But I'd like to also include parameters for Sunny and Rainy days.  Basically what I'm after is:

1. If currentPrecip = "Mostly Cloudy" Or "Cloudy" Or "Partly cloudy" - Display 'mostly-cloudy' gif
2. If current Precip = "Rainy", "Rain", "Thunderstorms", "Light drizzle" - Display 'rainy-gif' gif
3. If currentPrecip = "Sunny" Or "Clear" - Display 'sunnygif' gif.

I keep getting syntax errors when trying to write this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to nest the `If` statements.  What that does is, if the criteria for the first condition evaluates to `false`, instead of having a value for a `false` result, you have another `If` statement to evaluate.

```
If (
    currentPrecip = "Mostly Cloudy" Or "Cloudy" Or "Partly cloudy",
    'mostly-cloudy',
    If (
        currentPrecip = "Rainy" Or "Rain" Or "Thunderstorms" Or "Light drizzle",
        'rainy-gif',
        If (
            currentPrecip = "Sunny" Or "Clear",
            'sunnygif',
            Blank()
        )
    )
)
```

You could also make it a little simpler by eliminating the last `If` statement:

```
If (
    currentPrecip = "Mostly Cloudy" Or "Cloudy" Or "Partly cloudy",
    'mostly-cloudy',
    If (
        currentPrecip = "Rainy" Or "Rain" Or "Thunderstorms" Or "Light drizzle",
        'rainy-gif',
        'sunnygif'
    )
)
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you for laying that out for me!  Looks like it's working...just have to wait for a precipitation change.

Answer (score 0):

`If` function in Power Apps supports chaining of multiple "Conditions" & "ThenResults" as given in below syntax:

```
If( Condition1, ThenResult1 [, Condition2, ThenResult2, ... [ , DefaultResult ] ] )
```

**Documentation**: [If and Switch functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if)

---

So, for your requirements you can use the formula in simplest way like:

```
If (
    currentPrecip = "Mostly Cloudy" Or currentPrecip = "Cloudy" Or currentPrecip = "Partly cloudy",
    'mostly-cloudy',
    currentPrecip = "Rainy" Or currentPrecip = "Rain" Or currentPrecip = "Thunderstorms" Or currentPrecip = "Light drizzle",
    'rainy-gif',
    'sunnygif'
)
```

Use this formula in `Image` property of Image control.